# Opening a network file in Cytoscape using cmd and Python

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, cytoscape

So I have a python script that produces a networkx graph and exports it as .graphml and I want script to also be able to open cytoscape with the network loaded without any work on the users part. I understand:

```
cytoscape.bat -N C:\Somepath\with\a\networkx.graphml
```

and it works fine when I use it. As does:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Cytoscape_v3.0.0"
cytoscape.bat
```

However, I can't seem to get either `os.system` or `subprocess` to run properly, my current configuration is:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("cytoscape.bat", cwd="C:/Program Files/Cytoscape_v3.0.0")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

But the throws a file-not-found-exception.

I've been reading up on other stackoverflow posts and python docs on running .bats and doing cmd operations, and can get the basics to work. However, this seems somewhat more complicated, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong!

As requested I exceptions:

The file not found and incorrect path exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CytoScapeExporter.py", line 219, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen("cytoscape.bat", cwd="\"C:/Program Files/Cytoscape_v3.0
.0\"")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CytoScapeExporter.py", line 219, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen("cytoscape.bat", cwd="C:/Program Files/Cytoscape_v3.0.0
")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

A slightly different JVM error, it is produced by this code:

```
os.system("\"C:/Program Files/Cytoscape_v3.0.0/cytoscape.bat\"")

Error: missing `server' JVM at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.
dll'.
Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
C:\Program Files\Cytoscape_v3.0.0
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the full exception data?

Comment: Done, I've added a stranger JVM error and what os.system call produces it.

Comment: Are you running the Popen command in the cytoscape.bat directory? `cwd` changes the directory before executing the command, but [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) says: this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so **you can’t specify the program’s path relative to cwd**.

Comment: Ah. Well there's the problem. the `cwd` is the cytoscape.bat directory. Is this a problem specific to `subprocess`, or is there a `os.system` or some such work around?

Comment: It's not a problem, you just have to pass the full path to subprocess.Popen instead of just "cytoscape.bat".

Comment: So in the vein of: `p = subprocess.Popen("C:/Program Files/Cytoscape_v3.0/cytoscape.bat", cwd="C:/Program Files/Cytoscape_v3.0.` ?

Comment: It works! However, it brings up the same JVM error as seen above. I feel like this could be cytoscape related, and not a python problem.

Comment: Fixed it by creating an env dict for popon. However it now throws Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx7691m which is odd.

Comment: You could try changing the value (I suppose it's in cytoscape.bat), but I don't know if that will have any influence.

Comment: So to get it to work one must: set Java variable paths on clients pc,  and remove Cytoscape.vmoptions so it reverts to default. That's just a hassle. Thanks for the help with the cmd stuff, if you want to chuck up an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

"If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to cwd before it is executed. **Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to cwd.**"

You have to pass the full path of the command to subprocess.Popen.